# Why isn't the following forEach array loop returning undefined?

Tags: javascript

```
var amaList = ['announce', 'argue', 'demonstrate', 'express', 'hint', 'illustrate', 'imply', 'make', 'mean', 'pinpoint', 'point out', 'prove', 'reveal', 'show', 'signal', 'specify', 'suggest', 'attest', 'connote', 'denote', 'designatesta']

var hintList = amaList.forEach(function(s) {
  return s
})

console.log(hintList)
```

`hintList` logs `undefined`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you confusing `forEach` and `map` ? If not please precise what you expect and why.

Comment: [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: oh, why does map work and not forEach?

Comment: maybe this issue could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: What does that mean, "work" ? What do you want ?

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return anything.

Comment: `forEach` is not supposed to return anything. It simply executes the callback for its side effects.

Comment: @alexchenco Please [edit] your question and include what you expected to happen instead of getting `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var hintList = amaList.map(function(item) {
     //do something with item and return the wanted item
});
```

[Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't return anything.

Here's an exampe for using forEach:

```
amaList.forEach(function(item){ 
     console.log(item);
});
```